Recognizing Signed 16-bit RAW Files Based on Filename
I’ve been using ImageJ and noticed a helpful feature where dragging and dropping RAW files onto a dialog allows ImageJ to infer the file format and dimensions from the filename.
For example, when using a filename like example_u16_512x256.raw, ImageJ correctly identifies it as an unsigned 16-bit image with dimensions 512x256. However, I've encountered an issue when trying to use filenames for signed 16-bit images.
When I use filenames such as example_i16_512x256.raw, ImageJ incorrectly assumes it to be an unsigned 16-bit image instead of a signed 16-bit image. I have also tried other naming conventions like example_s16_512x256.raw and example_signed16_512x256.raw, but the same problem occurs.
Is there a specific filename convention I should use to ensure ImageJ correctly recognizes signed 16-bit RAW files?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Best regards,

Why do you think that ImageJ is inferring the format from the name? Wouldn't it make more sense for it to infer the format from the data?

It is EXTREMELY unlikely that ImageJ is looking at the filename at all.  It's looking at the contents.  It can't tell the difference between signed and unsigned.  You have to tell it that.

You've made an invalid assumption that the filename is being used. AFAIK, no program in existence does so - they all depend on the actual data to identify the file.

Based on your inputs, it seems that ImageJ primarily relies on the {width}x{height}.raw part of the filename to infer the image size, and then estimates the image format based on the file size and total data volume.
From what I've observed:
When using a filename like example_u16_512x256.raw, ImageJ correctly identifies the width and height of the image.
However, it appears that ImageJ cannot determine the signedness of the data purely based on the filename and data size. It defaults to assuming unsigned data unless explicitly specified.

Again, the filename has nothing to do with it. You can easily test this yourself - use a filename that contains no dimensional data whatsoever, and see what ImageJ gets from that file.

Thank you for your comments.
Just to clarify, when I mentioned "Raw files," I was referring to binary image formats, not the Raw image format from digital cameras.
ImageJ allows you to open binary files with "File > Import > Raw...". If you select a file name that follows a specific naming convention in the file selection dialog, the image size will be automatically identified from the file name.

I don't think there is an easy approach, if you want this to work per "drag and drop" however, below please find a short ImageJ-macro that imports signed 16bit raw images with file names such as "example_s16_512x256.raw":
msg=" properly named, signed 16bit raw image";
path=File.openDialog("Open a"+msg);
s=File.getName(path);
if (s.contains("s16")&&s.contains(".raw")) {
   w=s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("_")+1,s.lastIndexOf("x"));
   h=s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("x")+1,s.lastIndexOf("."));
   run("Raw...","open=[path] image=[16-bit Signed] width=&w height=&h");
} else
   exit("Not a"+msg);

You may assign a key-shortcut to the macro.

If you are able to write the above macro, surely you could equally parse the filename for u16 or s16 or u8 or s8 and open as unsigned/unsigned 8/16?

Sure, but this wasn't the OP's question! However, signed 8bit images aren't supported by ImageJ.
